# How do you gauge the Near Pin % of a transaction?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

In Recettear, when you're buying/selling, the tutorial gives you the base "range" of acceptable percents to offer to the customers. It seems that there's a magic number to put down in order to get the Near Pin bonus XP, and there's no real way to see this (understandably so, or else there'd be no real reward for doing so).

However, it seems exceedingly difficult to gauge this number when customers are both perfectly happy to buy things well below the given price range, and will typically pay the upper end of the spectrum as well. I'm *pretty sure* that I've hit Near Pin % bonuses on both high and low offers, though I could be wrong.

Does the Near Pin % fluctuate per transaction? Per customer type?

Comment: Related: [Optimal percentages for maximum profit and experience when buying and selling for each customer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11305/4797)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching around on the internet, I've found that apparently the best percentage to enter in order to get the most Near Pin bonuses is **104%** if you want to get the most out of Near/Full Pin bonuses for Merchant/Customer experience levels.  Each customer has a different percentage that they are willing to pay up to.  For example, you may have noticed the Little Girl is an incredible cheapskate, while the Guild Master has a considerably larger budget.

| Customer | Max Exp+rep (selling) | Max Profit (selling) | Max Exp+rep (buying) | Max Profit (buying) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Girl | 104% | 112%(?) | 70% | 52% |
| Woman | 104% | 118% | 70% | 52% |
| Old Man | 104% | 118% | 70% | 44% |
| Man | 104% | 127% | 70% | 39% |
| Guild Master | 104% | 127% | 70% | 41% |
| Louie | 104% | 118% | 70% | 38% |
| Charme | 104% | 127% | 70% | 47% |

> Yeah, it does seem like all the demo characters have the same level for pins. I’d recommend using 104% for all characters in the full game as well except Prime and Elan where I recommend selling at 100% so they don’t get huffy. I haven’t done much testing on the max prices of the full version-only characters but I’d recommend something like 114% for Chaiilou, 100% for Prime and Tielle, 110% for Griffe, 120%ish for Arma and 125% for Alouette. No idea on buy prices though everyone accepts 70% which gives the most rep and experience so going with that is a safe bet.

Information is from [this google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1RqChiJImA_N1ZnPEwPTmY5j3JFFPvc1G0mbQWnZ4YKY&pli=1#h.85xzz8-ezrhwk), which has a more detailed collection of collected statistics overall about the game.

Comment: This appears to have pulled data from the demo version. Any idea how close to true this reflects on the full version?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that this info is also accurate for the full version, as it's had recent edits since release.

Comment: I'll give it a shot when I get home. If it is, indeed, as simple as 104'ing every single offer to get the best average XP return, I'll be relieved, if not a little disappointed.

Comment: Marked as answer, tested last night, amazing how much XP you can rack up with just sticking to your guns and doing 104% every time.

Comment: Yeah, stacking Pin combos really really adds up quickly, and I can imagine it'll help a lot when trying to get xp for the higher Merchant levels.