# Optimal percentages for maximum profit and experience when buying and selling for each customer

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

Does anyone know the optimal buying/selling percentages of normal, increased and decreased-priced items to get the maximum experience points (high chance of pin bonus and customers should accept at first offer - no haggling; to get the maximum number of Just Combo bonuses possible) for each customer in the game (including Euria) while making profit as high as possible (*prioritize experience*)?

I have just finished the game and I am now trying to reach a high merchant level while trying to make the item inventory well stocked with items so I can play a 'New Game+' easily to get another adventurer's True Card.

Also, I would like to know the optimal buying/selling percentages for *maximum profit*, while making the customer not haggle and making the experience as high as possible (*prioritize profit over experience*).

Capitalism, Ho! Y'all!

Edits:

I found a Pin Bonus guide here: http://recettear.wikia.com/wiki/Pin_Bonus_Percentages but the data for some of the customers are missing (some are even wrong), and there is no data at all for decreased-priced items. (Although this maybe because it was written for the demo version of the game.) I am playing the Full version with the current latest v1.108 patch.

The 'always-sell-at-104%' technique mentioned in the link I put above and FallenAngelEyes' link in the comments works fine for getting maximum experience points when buying normal-priced items. I was wondering if this could be increased for some of the customers to get more profit while still maintaining a good chance of hitting the Pin Bonuses and Just Combo chains. Also, I need optimal buying/selling info for Euria, who was probably put in the game to break Just Combo chains. I also would like to know the elusive buying/selling info for increased-price and decreased-price items for all customers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you gauge the Near Pin % of a transaction?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7383/how-do-you-gauge-the-near-pin-of-a-transaction)

Comment: It looks like from galacticninja's question that the linked question does not account for all possible customers (though it does an adequate job for those characters present in the demo).

Comment: As a comment, as I was the one who asked the linked question above, I can verify that the suggested 104% target works *very* well for XP gain purposes (chaining pin bonuses). In terms of monetary gain, that I cannot speak for.

Comment: I think I remember reading that the customer preferences regarding prices are different for every game, though each individual holds to their own preference throughout it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still in progress of checking but, here:

Customer price data (Haggle usually, once at most)

| Name | Price Factor | Randomness | Purchase Factor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tear | 130% | ±2% | 35% |
| Louie | 120% | ±2% | 45% |
| Charme | 125% | ±2% | 40% |
| Caillou | 135% | ±3% | 30% |
| Tielle | 135% | ±3% | 30% |
| Elan | 135% | ±3% | 30% |
| Nagi | 135% | ±3% | 30% |
| Griff | 135% | ±3% | 30% |
| Arma | 135% | ±3% | 30% |
| Guildmaster | 130% | ±1% | 35% |
| Woman | 120% | ±3% | 45% |
| Man | 130% | ±4% | 35% |
| Old Man | 125% | ±8% | 40% |
| Girl | 115% | ±1% | 50% |
| Euria | N/A | ±5% | 200% |
| Alouette | 150% | ±1% | 15% |
| Prime | 105% | ±1% | 60% |

If you want to haggle, set your starting sale price at about 3%-5% higher than how much you want to sell it at first. Buying works similarly.

Customer price data (Combo, Sell)

| Name | Near Pin (Sell) | Just Pin Range (Sell) | Just Combo (Sell) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tear | 108% | 104%-108% | 108% |
| Louie | 108% | 104%-108% | 108% |
| Charme | 108% | 104%-108% | 108% |
| Caillou | 108% | 104%-108% | 108% |
| Tielle | 108% | 104%-108% | 108% |
| Elan | 108% | 104%-108% | 108% |
| Nagi | 108% | 104%-108% | 108% |
| Griff | 108% | 104%-108% | 108% |
| Arma | 108% | 104%-108% | 108% |
| Guildmaster | 108% | 104%-108% | 108% |
| Woman | 108% | 104%-108% | 108% |
| Man | 108% | 104%-108% | 108% |
| Old Man | 108% | 104%-108% | 108% |
| Girl | 108% | 104%-108% | 108% |
| Euria | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| Alouette | 108% | 104%-108% | 147% |
| Prime | 102%-104% | 102%-104% | 104% |

They'll buy at once at these prices. If you're lucky, you'll get a Near Pin or a Just Bonus.

Customer price data (Combo, Buy)

| Name | Near Pin (Buy) | Just Pin Range (Buy) | Just Combo (Buy) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tear | 70% | 67%-70% | 70% |
| Louie | 70% | 67%-70% | 70% |
| Charme | 70% | 67%-70% | 70% |
| Caillou | 70% | 67%-70% | 70% |
| Tielle | 70% | 67%-70% | 70% |
| Elan | 70% | 67%-70% | 70% |
| Nagi | 70% | 67%-70% | 70% |
| Griff | 70% | 67%-70% | 70% |
| Arma | 70% | 67%-70% | 70% |
| Guildmaster | 70% | 67%-70% | 70% |
| Woman | 70% | 67%-70% | 70% |
| Man | 70% | 67%-70% | 70% |
| Old Man | 70% | 67%-70% | 70% |
| Girl | 70% | 67%-70% | 70% |
| Euria | 350% | 350%-360% | 210% |
| Alouette | 70% | 67%-70% | 20% |
| Prime | 70% | 67%-70% | 70% |

They'll sell at once at these prices. If you're lucky, you'll get a Near Pin or a Just Bonus.

Answer (score 9):

Look first off, you don't really need to be too precise. The main thing is to only buy blue reduced items from the wholesellers. And then try really hard to only sell pink "in demand" items (these will sell for over 200%). Working like that, you will smash the final week target easily. When you sell e.g. an order of 3 things with a description of e.g. "something metal" to the Old Man, he will accept 240% for each, and you bought them for e.g 33k and are selling them for 100k each, you can make some massive profits.

For experience the main thing is to make sure that you get a lot of customers in for each session. Make sure the shop is stocked with some cheap crap, food is good, and in the middle of the style scale e.g. not too gaudy and then you will get a lot of customers. I also put expensive stuff in the shop window. Then you will hit regularly hit 128 XP.

The actual answer to your question is beyond me now. I wrote out all the percentages but then deleted the file because the end game is a bit of a grind and I knew I wasn't coming back. I found that, of course, the old man is more generous than the little girl, however, as well as this, I seem to remember that what they said was really important. Each type of shopper has their own little sayings e.g. they will come to the counter and say *something* and the thing that they say determines the price that they are willing to pay, so what I did was write out each and every sentence and used trial and error to work the optimum percentage for each sentence. If they tried to haggle then next time they used that same sentence, I would lower the percentage a little bit, and I continued like that until they accept the price without haggling.

Answer (score 6):

Aiming for for the 104-108% sell price isn't just for getting your xp bonuses maxed.  In fact, a more important outcome is getting those little hearts.  Every time you get a heart you have leveled your relationship with that customer.  In so doing you increase the amount of money they bring into the store (by x10?  I can't recall).  This is *crucial* because if you don't do this customers won't have enough money to buy and sell the expensive stuff you need to move to hit the targets.

Also, DanD is correct.  The *best* way to make money is to buy items when they are in low demand (blue colored) and then sell them when they are pink.  But you don't need to wait for that swing.  Going blue -> normal or normal -> pink will make you a *ton* of money.  Once you are selling the top tier items, you can't help but rake it in.

Comment: Good answer. I wish I could have two accepted answers here.