# How can I tell if people are selling stuff to me?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

I have a low tolerance for repetitive dialog. This means that when I'm manning the store front, I mash every key that might possibly speed up the text and ["get on with it"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1YmS_VDvMY).

This turns out to be bad for business: I don't always notice when someone comes in to sell me something rather than buy it... And let's just say buying something for 100+% of the base price makes for happy customers and a broke store owner.

Is there any way to tell whether someone's selling or buying when we skip directly to talking price?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to tell whether someone's selling or buying when we skip directly to talking price?

From: http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/604893-recettear-an-item-shops-tale/answers?qid=229370

The text color. If the text is in yellow, you're buying. If the text is white, you're selling.

> I don't always notice when someone comes in to sell me something rather than buy it... And let's just say buying something for 100+% of the base price makes for happy customers and a broke store owner.

With the above text color guideline in mind, just use the guide here for optimal buying and selling prices: http://recettear.wikia.com/wiki/Pin_Bonus_Percentages (Use the data here as a guide, as data in that wiki article is from the demo version of the game and could be incorrect for some characters. It also has missing info.)

A previous, related question of mine about the discrepancies in the above Recettear wiki link: [Optimal percentages for maximum profit and experience when buying and selling for each customer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11305/recettear-optimal-percentages-for-maximum-profit-and-experience-when-buying-and)

If your goal is to gain experience points as fast as possible, always selling at 104% to everyone is optimal for linking chain experience bonuses: [How do you gauge the Near Pin % of a transaction?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7383/how-do-you-gauge-the-near-pin-of-a-transaction/7388#7388)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I don't have a problem figuring out prices, so long as I know whether I'm buying or selling. The first part of your answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this same issue. I never was able to find an answer, and I'm unsure if there even is. I *do*, however, have some advice to prevent you from being the most generous item shop owner ever.

**Know What's in your Store**

If you're being offered an item that you are decidedly *not* stocking, or if the item in question is sparkling with the "SHOWCASE ITEM" it is relatively easy to determine whether they want to buy or sell.

**When in Doubt, just go for 100%**

If you want to be extra safe and hedge your bets, just go for the flat 100% price. Your customers will be happy, and though you might lose *some* profit on the transaction, compare the folly of selling an expensive item for 35%, or paying over 117% for an item of theirs.

When you reach a situation like this, if you have to guess, you've got a 50/50 % chance to lose money, or simply oversee another sale (like normal). If you don't want a potentially huge loss, simply stick to the median, and you create an option 3, and when considering "50% lose profit, 50% make normal profit" or 100% make *some* profit, it's easy to see why the third option is the most appealing.

Comment: Given the accepted answer, this advice now seems unnecessary.

Comment: @bwarner - unnecessary, but not useless or wrong. I had originally intended to post this as a comment anyway, but it grew too large for that.